# Which header shall I use? XMLHTTPRequest header or SOAP header?

Tags: c#, javascript, web-services, soap, xmlhttprequest

I have a XMLHTTPRequest that contains SOAP message.
I want to add guid that will identified the message and will be consume by C# web service.
The GUID goal is to identified specific user and supposed to escort all user requests for authentication purpose on server, This GUID is created at user login, saved on server and then for every request the request guid checked by server.

Should I use XMLHTTPRequest header like this:

```
setRequestHeader("GUID", this.requestGUID);
```

Or use SOAP Header

```
<?xml version="1.0"?<?xml version="1.0"?>
<soap:Envelope
xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-envelope"
soap:encodingStyle="http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-encoding">

<soap:Header>
  <GUID>someGUID...</GUID>
</soap:Header>
...
...
</soap:Envelope>
```

Is there any advantages for one of them?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the answer on your question is mostly a matter of taste. I personally would prefer to use `setRequestHeader` method: it take less space in the message and is not SOAP dependent (I personally like JSON more as SOAP).

If I would know more about the nature of the `GUID` value I would probably change my mind. If the GUID is the property of the data then the message body would be better choice. Having no more information as you posted in the question I stay by `setRequestHeader` choice.

Comment: The GUID goal is to identified specific user and supposed to escort all user requests for authentication purpose on server, This GUID is created at user login, saved on server and then for every request the request guid checked by server.

Comment: @DorCohen: It sounds even more as HTTP header. It remind me on setting of `Authorization` header of HTTP (the header can contain any custom authorization information too).

Comment: And what are you saying about linkerro answer? it's the opposite than your answer

Comment: @DorCohen: I started my answer with the words "I think that the answer on your question is mostly a matter of taste". I really think so. If you use SOAP you still can use Windows Integrated security or other HTTP based authentication. So the usage of HTTP headers is not evil (in my opinion). Moreover you should think about the late development of your application. Do you want definitively stay inside of SOAP protocol or you use it just for communication and can imagine to change to [OData](http://www.odata.org/) or some other? In the case you should be opened and can use HTTP possibilities too

Answer (score 0):

If your code has a SOAP message it should have a soap header.
Mixing SOAP messages with other headers might break some implementations of the SOAP stack. The implementation in .NET is particularly strict.

The XMLHTTPRequest header is used for restfull services which have different principles behind them.